# Using UIHint in combination with LINQ to SQL generated class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I used LINQ to SQL to generate a dbml file which contains the database model for my database table. I want to use UIHint to let MVC present some fields as DropDownLists or Checkboxes in edit mode. But if I change the file, it will be lost if it's been regenerated. How should I solve that issue? I'm quite new to MVC and still learning. I've set up a controller with views for all CRUD elements, but now I'm finetuning and I'm running into this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Linq-to-SQL auto-generates partial classes, you'll need to create a partial 'buddy class' where you will add your Data Annotations. Your buddy class mirrors portions of the auto-generated class that you need to modify. You tie them together with [MetadataType(typeof(BuddyClassName))] The partial buddy class and the auto-generated partial class will be merged together when you compile your project.

In an example given that:

- Your namespace is "Project.Models"
- Your Linq-To-Sql class is called "Products"

  ```
  using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

  namespace Project.Models
  {
    [MetadataType(typeof(ProductsMeta))]
    public partial class Products
    {
      // You can extend the products class here if desired.

      public class ProductsMeta
      {
        // This is a Linq-to-Sql Buddy Class      
        // In here you can add DataAnnotations to the auto-generated partial class

        [Key]
        public int ProductKey { get; set; }

        [Display (Name = "Product Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Name Required")]
        [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Must be under 255 characters")]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        [UIHint("MultilineText")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
      }
    }
  }
  ```

These articles were very helpful:

1. [ScottGu: ASP.NET MVC 2: Model Validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx)
2. [How to: Validate Model Data Using DataAnnotations Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141%28VS.100%29.aspx#Y692)
3. [Validating with Data Annotation Validators](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs)

Comment: Thank you very much! It took some time to read your post, due to an impediment but today, I used your example and it works very well. I'll read the articles to create custom templates for dropdown controls. I found the way to create them a few weeks ago, so I'll find them again I assume. I don't have a reputation so I can't give you a vote.

Comment: Your welcome. I've found this site to be very valuable in working through my own projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the entities directly you should create a partial class and add your annotations there. This way when the model is regenerated you will not lose your annotations.

Comment: If I do so, can I use the same object names and will VS merge both declarations?